# Activity not starting after passing intent object

Tags: android, object, android-intent, timepicker

I have been working to build this app, but for some reason it is not working. After clicking the next button, it shows that the " Unfortunately the app has stopped working". Here is the code. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out here. I can't find where the problem is

```
public DatePicker picker;
public TimePicker time;
public String dt,datei;
public String timei,t;
public int hour, min;
public String format = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datetimepicker);
    btnNxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNxt2);
    time = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    picker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    hour = time.getCurrentHour();
    min = time.getCurrentMinute();
    showTime(hour,min);
    t = timei;

    btnNxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(DateTimeActivity.this,
                    PhoneNumberActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("t",t);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public String showTime(int hour, int min) {
    if (hour == 0) {
        hour += 12;
        format = "AM";
    } else if (hour == 12) {
        format = "PM";
    } else if (hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
        format = "PM";
    } else {
        format = "AM";
    }
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(" : ").append(min)
            .append(" ").append(format);
    timei = str.toString();
    return timei;
}
```

}

This error is showing in the log file

```
Note: C:\Users\Arnab PC\AndroidStudioProjects\SendGreetings\app\src\main\java\com\example\sendgreetings\PhoneNumberActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: without the log stack trace, nobody can help you here with this type problem

Comment: Show log cat in error

Comment: PhoneNumberActivity is  declare in manifest file in?

Comment: @cyberlobe, shouldn't we wait for his stack trace first?

Comment: Yes PhoneNumberActivity is declared in manifest file

Comment: I updated the log file error

Comment: But, even if I remove that deprecated code, even then it is not working

Comment: After you remove deprecated code, you have still errors?

Comment: I had figured it out .. Thanks anyway